# Is the assignment of a root system to a semisimple Lie algebra functorial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

As described [here](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/01/22/the-category-of-root-systems/), we have a category of root systems, where a **morphism** from a root system $\Phi$ in a Euclidean space $E$ to a root system $\Phi'$ in $E'$ is given by a linear map $f: E \to E'$ such that $f(\Phi) \subseteq \Phi'$ and $f(\alpha) \dashv f(\beta) = \alpha \dashv \beta$ for all $\alpha, \beta \in \Phi$, where $\alpha \dashv \beta \mathrel{:=} 2 \frac{\langle \alpha | \beta \rangle}{\langle \beta | \beta \rangle} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\langle ~ |~  \rangle$ denotes the inner product on $E$. For isomorphisms of root systems, this last condition is in fact redundant, and follows automatically from the first two. This seems to be the "correct" notion of morphism for root systems: we have finite coproducts of root systems (which are oddly denoted by a product in most texts) and an initial object (the empty root system). Moreover, the Weyl group construction is a covariant functor on root systems.

Now, given a complex semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, we can assign to it a root system $\Phi$, given by the set of nonzero weights of the representation of a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h} \leq \mathfrak{g}$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ via the adjoint action.

This assignment of a root system to a complex semisimple Lie algebra is an invariant, in the sense that isomorphic Lie algebras have isomorphic root systems (and conversely). But is this construction functorial? That is given a morphism of semisimple Lie algebras $f: \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}'$, do we obtain a morphism of their root systems? If not a covariant functor, might this be a contravariant functor?

I am just learning about the classification of Lie algebras now and do not have a great handle on the material yet, but I have a feeling that this should be the case.

One point that was raised by Mariano Suárez-Alvarez in the comments is that the choice of Cartan subalgebra is not functorial. Nevertheless, in the end the construction of a root system does not depend on the choice of Cartan subalgebra, which leaves me hope that this construction might still be functorial.

If it is indeed functorial, then the classification of semisimple complex Lie algebras would have an elegant description in terms of this "root system" functor: it is strong monoidal, conservative, and reflects simple objects (irreducible root systems being the simple objects in the category of root systems). Furthermore, since the Weyl group of a root system is functorial, then the assignment of the Weyl group to a Lie algebra would simply be the composite of the two functors.

[Cross-post mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244893/is-the-assignment-of-a-root-system-to-a-complex-semisimple-lie-algebra-functoria)

Comment: I will need to think some more about this, but I think you should indeed get a contravariant functor. The morphism of Lie algebras gives a morphism $f_{\mathfrak{h}}: \mathfrak{h}\to \mathfrak{h}'$ of their Cartan subalgebras. The root system "lives" in the duals of these and $f_{\mathfrak{h}}$ gives a map $f_{\mathfrak{h}}^*: \mathfrak{h}'^*\to\mathfrak{h}^*$, which probably gives a morphism of root systems by virtue of $f$ being a morphism of Lie algebras (this last part is what I will need to think a bit more about).

Comment: That would be very nice if it were true! Since the Weyl group is a covariant functor on root systems, we would also get the Weyl group as a contravariant functor on semisimple Lie algebras.

Comment: There is no functorial Cartan subalgebra.

Comment: I realize that a choice of Cartan subalgebra is required, but if I understand correctly, the root system doesn't depend on the particular choice of Cartan subalgebra, so perhaps we can still functorially assign a root system?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Ahh, of course. Good point.

Comment: **Please** do **not** crosspost to MO. If needed, we can move the question there but having two copies is good for no one.

Comment: Sorry, I've seen others do this so I did not realize this was frowned upon. I wouldn't mind having it moved, or I can delete this copy if that's easier?